Lebesgue Measure - Disk
Probably a very easy question, but still want to check if I understood correctly.
Let $F$ be the unit flat disk in the $xy$-plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
$$
F=\left\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \text { and } z=0\right\}
$$
Then $\mathcal{L}^1(F)=$ $\infty$ as $F$ can be covered by infinitely many lines.
$\mathcal{L}^2(F)=Area (F)={\pi}$ and  $\mathcal{L}^3(F)=\operatorname{vol}(F)=0 $ since the disk is flat.
I am using the usual definition
If $A\subset\mathbb R^n$ is a $k$-cube ($k\leq n$) i.e can be written as $A=E_1\times\ldots \times E_n$ with for all $j=1\ldots k$ $E_{i_j}=[a_j,b_j]$ (where $1\leq i_1<\ldots<i_k\leq n$) and for all $l\notin\{i_j\;|\;j=1\ldots k\}$ $\lvert E_l\rvert=1$, the $k$-dimensional volume of $A$ is given by
$$
\operatorname{vol}^k(A)=\left(b_{1}-a_{1}\right)\cdots\left(b_{k}-a_{k}\right) .
$$
and for $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$
$$
\mathcal{L}^k(A)=\inf \left\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \operatorname{vol}^k\left(A_i\right): A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i\right\}
$$
where the infimum is taken over all coverings of $A$ by $k$-cubes.
Are the values of 1,2,3 - dimensional lebegue measure for $F$ correct?

Yes they are correct.
